# difference between page based application and view based application

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode4.6

I'm new in iOS development and I'm just following some tutorials on youtube, I'm confused between **page based application** template and **view based application** template. I'm using **xcode 4.6** and the tutorial I'm following has page based application using **xcode 4.0** using a view based application. Xcode 4.6 has no view based application.

What are the difference of page base application and view based application in Xcode? Are they the same?

Comment: what is page Base >>>?? u mean navigation base >??

Comment: page based application template for ios.

Comment: Page based applications are generally an example of books, pdf kind of application, where you need to play around with page with curl on bottom during flipping the page. whereas, a view based is the one with simple view on it, you can add your components on it and play around it, however it will not have navigation attached to it, whereas page based will have it by default for you. Navigation might have been through code/story board.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Page based application** and **view based applications** are just **templates** only that makes your job a little bit easier. Depending upon your template selection `Xcode` will automatically generate some files and use some controls. It is not necessary to start with such kind of template you can even start with an **empty application** . There you are designing from scratch. You can choose a template based on type of your application.

Inorder to find the difference just create applications using both templates and run it. **Page based application** uses **pageViewController**  that switches pages while swiping just like turn pages of a book. **single view application** creates a single view controller and its view. If you choose single  single view application initially dont worry. Add **pageViewController** and design properly, you can make it as a **Page based application**